# Remove python2 from my operating system without disturbing python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, uninstallation

I have python 2 and python 3 both installed in kali linux . I want to know ,'Is there any method to remove python 2 but not python 3 ???'.
I have searched at many places but not found any suitable answer.

Comment: Don't remove it, just mask it's presence using alias;